# Save button of dialog is not firing bean method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I'm trying to implement an edit functionality by using a dialog that loads row data from a data table. I'm able to load staff details fro the data table into the dialog and display save button accordingly. But my save button is not firing my bean method to save the updated record in the dialog.What could I be missing, Here are my codes,

1. the .xhtml file

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
       xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
       xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
       xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" 
       xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
       <h:head>
           <title>Asset Manager-Home</title>
       </h:head>
       <h:body>
           <p:layout fullPage="true">

               <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="200">
                   <h:outputText value="Home content." />
               </p:layoutUnit>

               <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="50">
                   <h:outputText value="All Rights Reserved." />
               </p:layoutUnit>

               <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="250" header="">
                   <h:form>
                       <p:panelMenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Home">
                               <p:menuitem value="Home" url="/faces/index.xhtml" />
                           </p:submenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Staff">
                               <p:menuitem value="Create Staff " url="/face/createStaff.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                               <p:menuitem value="Update Staff " url="/faces/updateStaff.xhtml" />
                               <p:menuitem value="All Staff " url="/faces/updateStaff.xhtml" />
                           </p:submenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Categories">
                               <p:menuitem value="Create Category" url="/faces/createCategory.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                               <p:menuitem value="Update Category" url="/faces/updateCategory.xhtml" />
                               <p:menuitem value="View Category" url="/faces/updateCategory.xhtml" />
                           </p:submenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Asset">
                               <p:menuitem value="Create Asset" url="/faces/createAsset.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                               <p:menuitem value="Update Asset" url="/faces/updateAsset.xhtml" />
                               <p:menuitem value="All Asset" url="/faces/updateAsset.xhtml" />
                           </p:submenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Asset Status">
                               <p:menuitem value="Create/Update Status Register" url="/faces/CreateStatus.xhtml" />
                           </p:submenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Assigned Asset">
                               <p:menuitem value="Assign Asset" url="/faces/assignAsset.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                               <p:menuitem value="Do Update" url="/faces/updateAssignAsset.xhtml" />
                               <p:menuitem value="View All" url="/faces/updateAssignAsset.xhtml" />
                           </p:submenu>
                           <p:submenu label="Reports">

                           </p:submenu>
                       </p:panelMenu>
                   </h:form>
               </p:layoutUnit>

               <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="250" header="Right">
                   <h:outputText value="Right unit content." />
               </p:layoutUnit>

               <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                   <p:separator id="customSeparator" style="width:1000px;height:20px" />
                   <p:panel header="All Staff" id="allstaff">

                       <h:form prependId="false" id="staffform">

                           <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="stf" value="#{allStaffTableBean.staffList}" 
                               paginator="true" rows="10" 
                               paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                               rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" 
                               selection="#{allStaffTableBean.selectedStaff}" 
                               emptyMessage="KoblaGasu:: No data to be found for displaying" 
                               rowKey="#{stf.uniqueID}">


                               <p:column sortBy="#{stf.uniqueID}" filterBy="#{stf.uniqueID}">

                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="Staff ID" />
                                   </f:facet>

                                   <h:outputText value="#{stf.uniqueID}" />
                               </p:column>

                               <p:column sortBy="#{stf.firstName}" filterBy="#{stf.firstName}">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="First Name" />
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <h:outputText value="#{stf.firstName}" />
                               </p:column>

                               <p:column sortBy="#{stf.lastName}" filterBy="#{stf.lastName}">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <h:outputText value="#{stf.lastName}" />
                               </p:column>

                               <f:facet name="footer">
                                   <div>
                                       <p:commandButton id="edit" value="Edit" update=":staffform:display" onclick="PF('StaffEditDialog').show()" />
                                       <p:commandButton id="delet" value="Delete" />
                                   </div>
                               </f:facet>
                           </p:dataTable>

                           <p:dialog id="StaffEditDlg" widgetVar="StaffEditDialog" modal="true" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" header="Edit Staff" closeOnEscape="true">
                               <h:panelGroup id="display">
                                   <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{allStaffTableBean.selectedStaff != null}">
                                       <h:outputLabel value="Staff ID" for="staffUniqueID" />
                                       <h:outputText id="staffUniqueID" value="#{allStaffTableBean.selectedStaff.uniqueID}" />

                                       <p:outputLabel value="First Name" for="firstName" />
                                       <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{allStaffTableBean.selectedStaff.firstName}" title="First Name" size="45" maxlength="45" />

                                       <p:outputLabel value="Last Name" for="lastName" />
                                       <p:inputText id="lastName" value="#{allStaffTableBean.selectedStaff.lastName}" title="Last Name" size="45" maxlength="45" />
                                   </p:panelGrid>

                                   <p:commandButton actionListener="#{allStaffTableBean.update}" value="Save" oncomplete="PF().hide();" />
                                   <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="StaffEditDialog.hide()" />
                               </h:panelGroup>
                           </p:dialog>
                       </h:form>
                   </p:panel>
               </p:layoutUnit>
           </p:layout>
       </h:body>
   </html>
   ```
2. The staff bean

   ```
   public class Staff implements Serializable
   {

       private String uniqueID;
       private String firstName;
       private String lastName;

       /**
        * Creates a new instance of Staff
        */
       public Staff()
       {

       }

       public Staff(String uniqueID, String firstName, String lastName)
       {
           this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
           this.firstName = firstName;
           this.lastName = lastName;
       }

       public void updateSaff(ActionEvent event)
       {
           boolean status = new StaffManager().updateStaff(uniqueID, firstName, lastName);
           System.out.println("Kobla::Update called in Staff.java");
       }

       /**
        * @ return string's
        */

       public String save()
       {
           StaffManager staffManager = new StaffManager();
           boolean status = staffManager.saveStaff(uniqueID, firstName, lastName);

           if(status == true)
           {

               return "index";
           }
           else
           {
               return "createStaff";
           }
       }

       /**
        * @return: method to call getSstaff for staff manager
        */
       public String searchStaff()
       {
           Staff myStaff = new Staff();

           myStaff = new StaffManager().getStaff(uniqueID);

           this.uniqueID = myStaff.getUniqueID();
           this.firstName = myStaff.getFirstName();
           this.lastName = myStaff.getLastName();

           return "updateStaff";
       }

       public String deleteStaff()
       {
           StaffManager staffManager = new StaffManager();
           boolean status = staffManager.delStaff(uniqueID);

           if(status == true)
           {
               return "index";
           }
           else
           {
               return "updateStaff";
           }
       }

       /**
        * @return the uniqueID
        */
       public String getUniqueID()
       {
           return uniqueID;
       }

       /**
        * @param uniqueID
        *            the uniqueID to set
        */
       public void setUniqueID(String uniqueID)
       {
           this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
       }

       /**
        * @return the firstName
        */
       public String getFirstName()
       {
           return firstName;
       }

       /**
        * @param firstName
        *      the firstName to set
        */
       public void setFirstName(String firstName)
       {
           this.firstName = firstName;
       }

       /**
        * @return the lastName
        */
       public String getLastName()
       {
           return lastName;
       }

       /**
        * @param lastName
        *      the lastName to set
        */
       public void setLastName(String lastName)
       {
           this.lastName = lastName;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString()
       {
           return "Staff{" + "uniqueID=" + uniqueID + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + '}';
       }
   }
   ```
3. And a dataTable bean

   ```
   public class AllStaffTableBean implements Serializable
   {
       private List<Staff> staffList;
       private Staff selectedStaff;

       /**
        * Creates a new instance of AllStaffTableBean
        */
       public AllStaffTableBean()
       {
           staffList = new ArrayList<>();

           staffList = new StaffManager().getAllStaff();

           for(Staff stf : staffList)
           {
               System.out.println("allstafftablebean:: " + stf);
           }
           {
               System.out.println("selectedStaff :: " + selectedStaff);
           }
       }

       public void update(ActionEvent event)
       {
           RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

           new StaffManager().saveStaff(selectedStaff.getUniqueID(), selectedStaff.getFirstName(), selectedStaff.getLastName());
           System.out.println("Update callded in allstafftablebean.java :: " + selectedStaff);
       }

       /**
        * @return the staffList
        */
       public List<Staff> getStaffList()
       {
           return staffList;
       }

       /**
        * @return the selectedStaff
        */
       public Staff getSelectedStaff()
       {
           return selectedStaff;
       }

       /**
        * @param selectedStaff
        *            the selectedStaff to set
        */
       public void setSelectedStaff(Staff selectedStaff)
       {
           this.selectedStaff = selectedStaff;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: next time be nice with your code, format it! ;)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I will

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell commandButton what do you want to process, try with:

```
 <p:commandButton actionListener 
  ="#{allStaffTableBean.update}" value="Save"   oncomplete="PF().hide();"
  process="@this,StaffEditDlg"/>
```

or:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener 
  ="#{allStaffTableBean.update}" value="Save"   oncomplete="PF().hide();"
  process="@this,@widgetVar(StaffEditDialog)"/>
```

For working with the data in the dialog, you have to process dataTable information (selected item) so:

```
<p:commandButton id="edit" value="Edit" update=":staffform:display"   
onclick="PF('StaffEditDialog').show()" process=":staffform:dataTable" />
```

I recommend working with another instance of Staff to edit, remember that instances are just references, so if you change the value (for any reason), will be updated to all variables that have that reference, look up Shadow clone or deep clone. I think with these code will gonna work. If not, add a comment.

Have fun!

Comment: The button is able to fire up the update method in the bean now but the edited data in the dialog is not being captured. It seems to me as though the data captured by the bean is the selected row in the data table and not the dialog.

Comment: Well, data in the dialog is still not being captured. Could that be caused by the fact that the dialog and the data table are in the same form ?

Comment: Try to put your dialog outside layout and layoutUnit.

Comment: Forget comment I posted, mmm, it's weird. I will try to replicate at night, after work.

Comment: What is your version of primefaces?